# Understanding START and END of LINKS in CIRCOS

Tags: circos

I'm reading the tutorials and got problems understanding the `start` and `end` of a `link`. 
For example, here are 3 links between hs1 and /hs[2-4]/

```
ID  start end   ID  start end
hs1 100   200   hs2 250   300
hs1 400   550   hs3 500   750
hs1 600   800   hs4 150   350
```

To my understanding that only two points are needed for a link. Just couldn't understand why 4 points are needed here. And the docs says only the start and end of the link as well as some other tutorials online.

Comment: I tried some test data and think it's the middle point between START and END that connected to the other.